# How to lazy load multiple components at a same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading

I have 2 components, I want to load all of them using lazy load something like

```
const A = lazy(() => import("../test/A")); 
const B = lazy(() => import("../test/B"));
```

This will create 2 separate bundles, and will import them when required.

But, **I want to create a single bundle** and when that bundle loads I should be able to use both above components.

I also don't want to create a single component containing both the above components as I want a separate route for both of them

I tried to do something like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-raman-mdqzc?file=/src/App.js

Can please somebody will explain me Is this type of functionality possible, If yes then how and what am I doing wrong

Comment: Have you tried `Promise.all()`?  Wouldn't that do what you want?  I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to manually control the code splitting - Is the automatic code splitting not working? Or is there another reason I didn't think of?

Comment: Hello @GarrettMotzner, actually lazy loading 2 components will create 2 separate bundles but I want only 1 bundle to load multiple components i.e. I myself want to control what components will rely on what bundles, but the major issue is that I want seperate routes for them

Comment: Hello @zero298, I want to create a single bundle that comprises the only components that I want but with seperate routes

Comment: You can control when to show the component by using intersection observer. Zero config and less weight library(~3kb). https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-observer-api

Answer (score 8):

There are probably some tuning options in the code splitter that might better accomplish what you are trying to achieve. But if you don't want to mess around with those (or they are not available to change because you are using a preset configuration), then perhaps you can combine the modules into a single file, and lazy load that "combo module".

To do that, we first need to know how `lazy` determines what component in a module to load, and what types of objects it expects. From the docs:

> The `React.lazy` function lets you render a dynamic import as a regular component.
>
> `React.lazy` takes a function that must call a dynamic `import()`. This must return a `Promise` which resolves to a module with a default export containing a React component.
>
> The lazy component should then be rendered inside a `Suspense` component, which allows us to show some fallback content (such as a loading indicator) while we’re waiting for the lazy component to load.
>
> You can place the `Suspense` component anywhere above the lazy component. You can even wrap multiple lazy components with a single `Suspense` component.

So according to that, if you want to use `lazy()` to wrap the module, then you have to have a component as the `default` property of the module. So it won't allow you to automatically use a module that uses named exports as a component. *However*, you can easily make a promise that transforms a named export to a default export, and wrap that in lazy:

```js
// in comboModule.js:
export A from '../test/A'
export B from '../test/B'

// in the code that needs lazy modules
  const A = lazy(() => import('./comboModule').then((module) => ({default: module.A})))
  const B = lazy(() => import('./comboModule').then((module) => ({default: module.B})))
```

Note that we have to call `import` inside the initializer function passed to `lazy`, or the import will start immediately. Part of `lazy`'s benefit is that is lets you wait until the parent component renders the lazy component before loading. However, `import()` should cache the result from the first import, and only load the code once.

In the initializer function, we use `then` to transform the result of `import()` from something like `Promise({A: <Component>, B: <Component>})` to what lazy expects from the initializer function: `Promise({default: <Component>})`

Now we have two lazy components that both source from one module file.

Resources:

- [React code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)
- [import/export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Re-exporting_Aggregating)
- [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) (`then` returns a promise)

Comment: Thanks for this brief explanation, will try implement this

Comment: I have tried this solution, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Suspense for waiting both of them. There are two bundles, but you can wait of loading both of them

```js
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./routes/About'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Hello @IT's Bruise, this doesn't answer my query as this works the same like creating two bundles and will use when required, straight forward lazy load, please read my question again I specially mentioned I want a single bundle not multiple

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility function that generalizes what @garrett-motzner said in his answer:

```
import {lazy} from 'react';

export const multiLazy = moduleLoaderArray => {
  const promises = Promise.all(moduleLoaderArray.map(loader => loader()));
  return moduleLoaderArray.map((m, index) =>
    lazy(() => promises.then(results => results[index]))
  );
}
```

Works like a charm like this:

```
const [A, B] = multiLazy([
  () => import("../test/A"),
  () => import("../test/B"),
]);
```

So no need to create an intermediary component file (besides for the utility function of course)

I chose this syntax to stick as close as possible to the `React.lazy` one, but it could be modified to get `multiLazy(['../test/A', '../test/B'])` if preferred and often used.

Comment: Hm, I understood the request to be importing multiple named components from the same module file, not multiple modules from multiple files. Your implementation seems to be still importing the default module from multiple files. It seems to be solving a subtly different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy wrapper to the `import` statement to give `React.lazy` what it wants:

```
const bundle = new Proxy(import("../CombineModule"),{
  "get":function (esm,key){
    return esm.then(function (m){
      return {"__esMODULE":true,"default":m.default[key]};
    });
  }
});

var CompA = React.lazy(() => bundle.A)
var CompB = React.lazy(() => bundle.B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Garrett Motzner answer I made this helper for loading named components:

```
// in comboModule.js:
export default from '../test/A'
export B from '../test/B'

// in the code that needs lazy modules
const m = () => import('comboModule')
const ADefault = lazy(m);
const BNamed = lazy(m, m => m.B);


// the new lazy helper function:

export function lazy<T extends React.ComponentType<any>, Q extends { default: T }>(
    factory: () => Promise<Q>,
    selector?: (arg: Q) => () => JSX.Element
) {
    if (!selector) return React.lazy(factory);
    return React.lazy(() =>
        factory().then((module) => ({ default: selector(module) }))
    );
}
```

It does need a default export to exists or otherwise TypeScript will complain about that, but you can also load named components from the module.