# How to code split multiple React routes into one file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, react-lazy-load

I currently have the following lazy component imports:

```
const LazyDashboard = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/app/Dashboard'));
const LazyProfile = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/app/Profile'));
```

Then in the routes,

```
{userToken && <><Route exact path="/app" element={<LazyDashboard/>}/> 
                <Route exact path="/app" element={<LazyProfile/>}/></>}
```

- Going to the dashboard, a chunk is loaded in. Good!
- Going to the profile, another chunk is loaded in.. Not good! How do I mark these two imports to be bundled in the same chunk?

Is there any way to do this with React.lazy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lazy load multiple components at a same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464342/how-to-lazy-load-multiple-components-at-a-same-time)

Comment: @MohitKushwaha I somehow couldn't get that work locally, I'll give it another shot though, thanks!